# Why am I suddenly getting Missing Template errors with edge Rails (2.3)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After freezing edge rails, all my controller examples are failing with
MissingTemplate errors.
e.g., "Missing template attachments/create.erb in view path app/views"

Trying to actually render the views gives me the same error.

I noticed I can fix most of them by using respond_to but I usually
never use it. I almost always only need to respond to one format in
one action so I omit respond_to and let Rails figure out which file to
render.

Does Rails suddenly require respond_to blocks in every action as of 2.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found this, which answers my question:

http://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1590-xhrs-require-explicit-respond_to